# Чтение определённых символов строки

Tags: python

У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором находится несколько строк (5 например), в каждой из которых 11 символов типа byte. Из каждой строки необходимо считать только символы с 6 по 9 включительно. У меня получилось считать нормально 1 строку, а вот с остальными ерунда какая-то:

```
for t in range (epoch_num):
     tline = Tfile.read(9)[5:]

     print("Строка",tline)
     print("Количество символов",len(tline))
     print("Индекс",t)
     time[t] = int.from_bytes(tline,"little")
```

Comment: `.read(9)` — что-то не видно, чтобы вы где-то как-то пропускали оставшиеся 2 символа в строке

Comment: В теории я думал, что `.read(9)` должна выдавать мне первые 9 символов строки, а `[5:]` должна отсекать первые пять. С первой строкой так и вышло, но во второй уже мне выдало со 2 по 5ый символ

Comment: Ну так а ещё 2 символа из первой строки никуда не испарились же

Comment: (а может даже 3 символа, если вы забыли упомянуть наличие символа переноса строки)

Comment: Нет, про символ переноса я помню. 11 это с учетом переноса. Вы хотите сказать, что во второй итерации он начинает считывать с первой строки и переходит во вторую? Я просто думал, что он перейдет к след. строке сразу

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет ничего, что заставило бы кого-то где-то «перейти к след. строке»

Comment: Делайте прямо по написаному вами же в описании, просто подставьте правильные цифры: `tline = Tfile.read(11)[5:9]`